# Why is Hibernate @Filter annotation is not working with a WebSphere shared library?

Tags: hibernate, websphere-8, hibernate-filters

We are deploying our Spring + JPA + Hibernate web application in WebSphere.  In that application, we are packaging all our hibernate model objects as a separate jar file and keeping as a shared library reference. Our model object is annotation based entity classes.

The problem we are facing is apart from the `@org.hibernate.annotations.Filter`, FilterDefs annotation all the annotations are working fine. When I call the  `session.enableFilter("activeRecordFilter");` I get an Exception like:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No such filter configured [activeRecordFilter]
```

Our model object definition is like this

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef(name = "activeRecordFilter", defaultCondition =     "ACTV <> 'N'")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Filter(name = "activeRecordFilter")
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "ASSCTN", schema ="METADATA")
public class Association implements Serializable {

/**
 * serialVersionUID to validate serialized object
 */
```

Exception Trace

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No such filter configured [activeRecordFilter]
at     org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getFilterDefinition(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1204)
at org.hibernate.engine.LoadQueryInfluencers.enableFilter(LoadQueryInfluencers.java:127)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.enableFilter(SessionImpl.java:2035)
at com.metadata.common.baseclass.GenericDAOImpl.changeSoftDeleteFilterStatus(GenericDAOImpl.java:1228)
at com.metadata.common.baseclass.GenericDAOImpl.populatePredicateList(GenericDAOImpl.java:1044)
at com.metadata.common.baseclass.GenericDAOImpl.getIFGetResponse(GenericDAOImpl.java:425)
at com.metadata.common.baseclass.GenericDAOImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$db8e9c53.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
at com.metadata.common.repository.EntityRepository$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$22a81be7.getIFGetResponse(<generated>)
at com.metadata.metadatamodule.dao.GetServiceDAO.getResults(GetServiceDAO.java:51)
at com.metadata.metadatamodule.bo.GetServiceBO.getResults(GetServiceBO.java:67)
at com.metadata.metadatamodule.bo.GetServiceBO$$FastClassByCGLIB$$42f9d8cc.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
at com.metadata.metadatamodule.bo.GetServiceBO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$78933e6b.getResults(<generated>)
at com.metadata.metadatamodule.genericservice.GetService.getResults(GetService.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at
```

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere Application Server does not search shared libraries for Java EE annotations.  Annotations will only be processed in JAR files physically contained within the EAR/WAR.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my concern is apart from `@FilterDef` and `@Filter` annotations the other annotations like `@Entity`, `@Table` and some custom annotation that defined for our project specific settings also working fine when the entity jar resides in the shared library.